# build.xml version.tag for system tools 14, syntax?

Tags: android, ant

The new default build.xml has the following section:

```
    <!-- Import the actual build file.

         To customize existing targets, there are two options:
         ....
         (text removed for brevity)
         ....
         ***********************
         ****** IMPORTANT ******
         ***********************
         In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
         in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
    -->
    <!-- version-tag: 1 -->
```

Is it sufficient to replace the '1' with 'custom' and leave the line commented out in order to stop the file being overwritten? Or is it necessary to uncomment it, and if so what is the correct syntax?

Comment: What do you mean "new default build.xml"? What tool did you use to generate it?

Comment: @Alex - The ant_rules.xml file that was imported automatically by a project's build.xml in previous SDKs has been replaced by a 'build.xml' in the SDK's Ant directory.

Answer (score 6):

Just replace '1' with 'custom':

```
<!-- version-tag: custom -->
```